# Placing a shape on a grid

Tags: geometry, reference-request, optimization

I am interested in a certain kind of geometrical optimisation problems. I will illustrate it on a semi-concrete example:

> You are given a two-dimensional shape, say a polygon, and a rectangular grid. The polygon should be placed in such a way in the plane that the number of complete rectangles in its interior is maximal.

This problem will usually have more than one solution, but I am only interested in finding at least one of them. A method to prove that the solution is optimal would also be nice, and information about generalisations would be interesting too.

But for the moment I am mainly interested in the specific problem described above. Has someone written about it, and is there a general theory that helps to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: for *[Pick's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem)* ($AREA = I+\frac{B}{2}$-1) if there are more integer points contained in the polygon  ( *I* ), then there are more chance to find some rectangles...so you have to place the polygon in order to have the least number of lattice points that are also in the polygon's perimeter ( *B* )...